# Is it possible to turn off both 3G and LTE and only use 2G on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

Tomorrow, I am leaving the US and traveling internationally.  I added Sprint's "Global Roaming" plan to my phone.  The details of the plan are as follows: "*Unlimited basic data with speeds up to 2G* and unlimited text in any of our Sprint Global Roaming countries at no charge with calling for just $.20/min. For a full list countries, visit sprint.com/globalroaming" (emphasis added).

My question is - how can I turn off both 3G and LTE and only use 2G on my iPhone?  As far as I can tell, the only options are to turn off LTE or to turn off data completely.

It's important for me to figure this out because I don't want my phone accessing 3G and/or LTE while I'm abroad in case it puts outrageous charges on my phone bill due to 3G and LTE not being part of the "Global Roaming" plan.

Does anybody know if what I'm asking is possible?

(In case it helps, I have an iPhone SE running iOS 10.3.1.)

Comment: Usually when a cell provider offers you "speeds up to 2G" it just means it will use whatever normal 3G/4G tower you're on and throttles the speed down to about 128 Kbps. You can ask sprint if you have to enable any special settings or if this is the case here.

Comment: Thanks, @kal-al!  I'm going to call Sprint in the morning to confirm, but you're probably right.

Answer (score 1):

Settings → Cellular Data → Cellular Data Options → Voice & Data → 2G.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Depending on your locale, Cellular Data may be called Mobile Data, as shown in the screenshots (UK). This feature is dependent on carrier support. If the feature does not exist for you, contact your carrier.

Comment: This is not at all what I'm seeing in my settings...  I'm thinking that it's different depending on the carrier.